# lldb - attach to target Mac over ethernet after a kernel panic

Tags: macos, kernel, lldb, iokit, kernel-extension

I am trying to debug a kernel panic in our kext. I can attach to the target Mac over ethernet if I:

1. cause an NMI using
2. add an IOPanic call to my kext and cause it to be executed
3. use Dtrace to invoke a panic

However if I reproduce the kernel panic which I am investigating, the Mac just restarts.

How can I make the Mac wait for me to attach with lldb rather than restarting?

My target configuration is:

- Mac is 2021 M1 Pro 14" MacBook Pro
- macOS 14.2 (23C64)
- Network: Apple Thunderbolt 3 <-> Thunderbolt 3 adapter + Apple Thunderbolt 2 to ethernet adapters
- Boot-args = "debug=0x44 wdt=-1 kdp_match_name=en8" (I have also tried debug=0x104C0C)

I have tried creating kernel cored dumps, installing either a release or debug build of the kext.

When I first started investigating this kernel panic, I could attach if the kernel panic occurred with the Apple supplied build of our kext but not with the test one I built.  After a week of testing, I can no longer attach with the Apple supplied build.